# Give a unique row Id to every row in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I need to give a unique rowID to every row of a asp.net gridview. Default behavior is it doesn't give any row to  the `<tr>` generated. How to achieve this?

```
    <tr id="UniqueID" class="orbox" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background-color: AliceBlue; font-size: 11px; cursor: move;" align="center">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

**Edit: See above code, I am asking for the HTML ID `id="UniqueID"`.**

Comment: Give us some example code! We are not supposed to write the code for you. I cant do anything if you dont elaborate your answer more than throwing darts in the dark.

Comment: You can give unique id attribute to tr in GridView RowDataBound Event Handler.

Comment: UniqueId property is readonly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place on code behind a `public int cRowID = 0;` on the page class, and then place on the GridView where you won to use this ID, the `<%=cRowID++%>`.

eg:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
    <ItemTemplate ><%=cRowID++%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

To place the id on the row you can use the `RowDataBound` grab the row and add as attribute:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        row.Attributes["id"] = cRowID.ToString();
        cRowID++;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were creating the DataGridView programatcially then you can assgn unique value to the GridViewRow.Id http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow_properties

Comment: Sorry, but where is this id in the page that you have type ?

Comment: This is not the one is ask here, is the ID of the control of each row, when you add it pro grammatically.

Comment: @Aristos this is what im suggesting in my answer saying if u were creating it programatically

Comment: The grid view is not make this rows programmatically, is make them automatically from the data. This is not work.